# Make C# web application to communicate with a Windows Form via named pipes?

Tags: c#, named-pipes

I am new to programming. Right now I am stuck with developing a C# web application that should be able to communicate with a Windows Form via named pipes? Can this be possible? If possible, how?

Note: Web application will be on the server and Windows Form will be on the client.

Comment: Why don't you say exactly what you want to achieve rather than describe how you think you might be able to achieve it. What sort of web applcation is it? Why do you want to communicate to the client? Can't you use a pull model rather than a push one (i.e. the client request information from the web application rather than the web applciation send data to the client)?

Comment: The choice of using named pipes looks a little bit strange for someone new to programming. Why have you gone for such design choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be wrong, but named pipes (specifically, the NetNamedPipeBinding in WCF - thanks Chris) are strictly inter-process IIRC.

You'd be better off a hosting WCF service on the server and connecting to that via the web-app and the Windows Forms app (assuming you can work with .Net 4).

Comment: You are wrong, actually. Named Pipes can be used for communication between machines on a LAN. Where you might be getting confused is that in WCF, the NetNamedPipeBinding only works on the same machine and does not support remote Named Pipes.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Chris. I am building a WCF based system, so you are 100% correct as to the root of my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Does [this article](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/interprocess-communication-using-named-pipes-in-csharp) help?

Taken from *there*:

> (...) working code which you can
>   download and view.
>
> [PipeClient.zip](http://www.switchonthecode.com/sites/default/files/43/source/PipeClient.zip) and
>   [PipeServer.zip](http://www.switchonthecode.com/sites/default/files/43/source/PipeServer.zip)
>
> These zip files each contain a Visual
>   Studio 2005 solution with working code
>   and a GUI for testing communication
>   between the client and the server.

Comment: that example includes invoke commands which wont work at a web app i would be glad if i could find an web app with named pipes example.

Comment: This sample code (in the main answer) predates the .NET Framework classes which support Named Pipe communication (System.IO.Pipes namespace). No reason to use it now that we have supported .NET types to use instead. The second link in the comment above is also irrelevant to the OP question as it concerns WCF Named Pipe binding which will only work on the same machine.